# wpa_supplicant error code -100

Tags: networking, network-manager

Every 2 minutes the following message appears in syslog:

```
hslaptop wpa_supplicant[741]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
```

wlp5s0 is my wifi device. Content of /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
match-device=driver:iwlwifi
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[logging]
level=INFO
domains=WIFI
```

sudo ip a returns the following:

```
wlp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 
qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:21:5d:b5:9a:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Activating the link (sudo ip link set wlp5s0 up) does not change anything.

Is this "works as designed"?
Regards
H. Stoellinger

Comment: I had the same issue, mu wifi is configured as hotspot, and what worked for me is to remove "timestamp" from my /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION_NAME.nmconnection. What is weird if that I added it back and still don't have the log